# Launchd script's output not being logged to system.log

Tags: syslog, launchd

Sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello?"
... (other things)
```

When run via launchd, it definitely runs (the other things are being done) but nothing shows up in /var/log/system.log. I'm running OS 10.9 Mavericks.

I tried replacing that line with

```
syslog -s "HELLO?"
```

but that also shows nothing. I should also add that I'm running the launchd script as a login script but specifying that it run as a daemon user. The user does not have root access. However, I've also tried running syslog as root, and still, nothing shows up in the logs.

This happens on multiple systems.

Comment: Same problem, I can see my script is running but nothing is shown in the system log.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108717/launchd-scripts-output-not-being-logged-to-system-log

Replace "echo" with "logger". Wonder where the output of echo goes.